# Ubuntu and xubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu and xubuntu in the same PC? If yes, the. Please guide me, thanks.

Edit: the release for Ubuntu is 16.04 and the release for xubuntu is 20.04, these are the releases I want..

Comment: Yes.  Install one, then install the other (using *Install Alongside* or *Something-else* and create/use a different partition for the install).   Here is the QA *(Quality Assurance) testcase* (http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/419/builds/223023/testcases/1301/results) for what you are asking for in Xubuntu *hirsute* (you didn't provide release details, I chose the current *development* cycle).   It's almost identical to the Ubuntu one if you move & look at that *testcase* too, as both use `ubiquity` as their installer

Comment: The release I want for Ubuntu is 16.04 as that is the last release my PC can support, I want to use xubuntu 20.04 as the release for xubuntu, and also, does xubuntu have a install along side option?

Comment: If you opened the link I provided (*which was given only by example*), it was for Xubuntu; which has the same options as Ubuntu Desktop as they both use the `ubiquity` installer (Ubuntu Server uses a different installer, as does Lubuntu).  You've given no specs as to why Ubuntu 16.04 is the latest (it reaches EOL in only a few months), given Xubuntu is not that dissimilar in requirements (the machine I'm replying on is from 2009 & both work fine; Xubuntu 18.04 LTS is the last x86 release that somewhat differs in having 32-bit architecture available)